# Changing ENTER function to TAB

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form where I'd like the action of ENTER to move to the next input field instead of submitting the form.  I've tried the code below, and a hundred variations, but I'm clearly doing something wrong.
[image]

Line 24 always calculates 0 length so 27 never executes. 
Here it is as text instead of an image:

```
$('form input').keydown(function(e) {   
    // The this keyword is <div id="input_form">
    if(e.keyCode == 13){  

        e.preventDefault(); // cancel default 13 key behaviour (submitting form)  
        var n = $(this).next('input').length;
        console.log("nexts=" + n);
        if( $(this).next('input').length) {  // if there's another field
            $(this).next('input').focus();  // move focus to next field in form
        }
        else {
            $(this).blur();
        }

     }
 });
```

The form is

```
 <form action="" class="my_input_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="my_input_form_5" method="post" name="">

   <!--            First Name            -->
    <div id="first_name_wrap" class="field_wrap" >
        <label for="first_name" id="first_name_label" class="form_label">First Name</label>
        <br />
        <input id="first_name" class="field_input" name="first_name" placeholder=""  type="text" value="<?php echo $first_name?>">

        <div class="form_field_error" id="first_name_error"  style="display:none;"></div>
    </div>

    <!--            Last Name            -->
    <div id="last_name_wrap" class="field_wrap"> 
        <label for="last_name" id="last_name_label" class="form_label">Last Name</label>
        <br />
        <input id="last_name"  class="field_input" name="last_name" placeholder=""  type="text" value="<?php echo $last_name?>">
        <div class="form_field_error" id="last_name_error"  style="display:none;"></div>
    </div>
```

Does anyone see the problem?

Comment: why is the first code as image? can you provide it as text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

> Get the immediately following **sibling** of each element in the set of
>   matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next
>   **sibling** only if it matches that selector.

You have a parent div first, which means `.next("input")` is empty, because there is no sibling element. You need to do something like:

```
$(this).parent().next(".field_wrap").find("input").length
```

This will:

1. Go to the parent element of `$(this)`
2. Go to the next element (being the next element with `class="field_wrap"`)
3. Find the first input-element
4. Grab the length

Comment: Thanks.  i got it!  If Iength in $(this).parent().next(".field_wrap").find("input").length is non-zero I move the focus there with $(this).parent().next(".field_wrap").find("input").focus(); and that moves the focus to the next input.  I have a feeling that there's a more elegant way to do this, but it does do what I want.